# If it Safe to Expose Geth RPC to Public Internet

Tags: go-ethereum, security, rpc

I just spun up a geth node on my home server with flags `--http.addr=0.0.0.0 --http.vhosts=* --http.corsdomain=* --ws --ws.origins=* --ws.addr=0.0.0.0`. I am using a nginx reverse proxy to make it accessible at eth.mydomain.com. I did not create any accounts or private keys within geth, so getting my funds stolen is not applicable.

Are there any security risks of having my RPC be publicly exposed? I would imagine DoS/DDoS attacks would be the only vulnerability but are there others I haven't thought of?

If so, what would be a safe authentication method? I don't think basic HTTP auth would work within metamask or web3js, or am I mistaken about this?

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal:

```
sudo apt install apache2-utils -y
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.gethauth username
```

then in your nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    
    location / {
        auth_basic "Protected Area!";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.gethauth;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8545/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

in web3js you put "http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@IPADDRESS"